# In service console, how to tell when user switches to navigation tab or closes all tabs

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console, custom-console-components

I've been working on a custom console component that displays solutions, and opens them as a subtab if user is viewing a tab, and opens as primary tab otherwise.

Open as subtab works properly.  I'm using the `onFocusedPrimaryTab` and `getFocusedPrimaryTabId` methods to keep a variable named parentTabIdrXt in sync.

The only thing that doesnt work is when a user closes the last tab, or when user switches to navigation tab.

When the last tab is closed, the `getFocusedPrimaryTabId` method appears to retain the value of the last-closed tab (or maybe i'm doing something wrong).

When user switches to navigation tab, the most recent tab Id is stored in the parentTabIdxRt variable.

So, my question - is there a method or a better approach that would allow me to open solution in a primary tab when user is on the navigation tab?  Both of the scenarios above result in the user going to the navigation tab.  I could not find a suitable method or example in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_methods_tabs.htm).

Here is the code for the visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Solution" recordSetVar="sols">

<apex:variable value="{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))}" var="instanceURL"/>

<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/38.0/integration.js"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var primaryTabIdxRt;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function refreshPrimaryTabId() {
            sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(processTab);
            }
            var processTab = function processTab(result) {
                primaryTabIdxRt = result.id;
                console.log('primaryTabIdxRt RefreshTab  = '+ primaryTabIdxRt);
        }
        sforce.console.addEventListener(sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.CLOSE_TAB,
                                refreshPrimaryTabId);
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
        var eventHandler = function (result) {
            primaryTabIdxRt = result.id;
            console.log('primaryTabIdxRt onFocusedPT = ' + primaryTabIdxRt);
        }
        sforce.console.onFocusedPrimaryTab(eventHandler);
</script> 


<script type="text/javascript">
        function openSolution(recURL) {
            console.log('OpenSolutionInitial = ' + primaryTabIdxRt);
             if (primaryTabIdxRt === null || primaryTabIdxRt == 'null') {
                console.log('OpenInPrimaryTabNull = ' + primaryTabIdxRt);
                sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null,recURL,true);
                }
            else if (primaryTabIdxRt === undefined) {
                console.log('OpenInPrimaryTabUnd = ' + primaryTabIdxRt);
                sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null,recURL,true);
                }
            else {
                console.log('OpenInSubtab = ' + primaryTabIdxRt);
                sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabIdxRt,recURL,true); 
            }    
        }
</script>  

<apex:pageBlock >

        <apex:form >
            <apex:panelGrid >
                <apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1" id="selList">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="list"  />
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!listViewOptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:panelGrid>
                </apex:form>
                <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto; height:300px; padding-right:3px;">
                <apex:pageBlockTable var="s" value="{!sols}" id="list">
                    <apex:column ><a href="#" onclick="openSolution('{!instanceURL}/{!s.Id}');">{!s.SolutionName}</a></apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>                
                </apex:outputPanel>    
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId()` again in `OpenSolution()` method before `if` conditions, then it will take correct `primaryTabIdxRt`

```
function openSolution(recURL) {
    sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(processTab, true);

    if (primaryTabIdxR.......){
    }
}
```

Please refer my answer in your last question [Console component tries to open in subtab when primaryTabId is null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158982/console-component-tries-to-open-in-subtab-when-primarytabid-is-null/158990#158990)

**Update**

Can you please take this code and let me know if that meets your ideal scenario (user is viewing nav tab, then the solution would open as a primary tab). For me this is working. Again I am opening dummy Lead record as opposed to Solutions.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">

    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/29.0/integration.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var primaryTabIdxRt;

        function refreshPrimaryTabId() {
            alert('inside refreshPrimaryTabId');
            sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(processTab, true);
            }

            var processTab = function processTab(result) {
                primaryTabIdxRt = result.id;
                alert('primaryTabIdxRt=' + primaryTabIdxRt);

            }

            function testOpenPrimaryTab() {
                recURL = 'https://cs21.salesforce.com/00Qq0000004iHC2';  //lead id
                sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(processTab, true);

                alert('OpenSolutionInitial = ' + primaryTabIdxRt);

                 if (primaryTabIdxRt == null || primaryTabIdxRt == 'null') {
                    alert('OpenInPrimaryTabNull = ' + primaryTabIdxRt);
                    sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null,recURL,true);
                    }
                else if (primaryTabIdxRt == undefined) {
                    alert('OpenInPrimaryTabUnd = ' + primaryTabIdxRt);
                    sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null,recURL,true);
                    }
                else {
                    alert('OpenInSubtab = ' + primaryTabIdxRt);
                    sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabIdxRt,recURL,true); 
                } 
                window.location.reload();
            }

    </script>
    <apex:form >
         <a href="#" onclick="testOpenPrimaryTab(); return false;">Click here</a>

      <apex:commandButton onclick="refreshPrimaryTabId(); return false;" title="ClickMe" value="Refresh Primary Tab ID" rerender="selList" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I missed that in your previous answer - that works quite well!  The only scenario it doesnt cover is when user goes to navigation tab, but still has a primary tab open.  My ideal scenario is that if user is viewing nav tab, then the solution would open as a primary tab, but doesnt seem to be any method that will tell when user is on navigation tab?

Comment: Can you please take this code, create a separate page and try to run this code, It seems to me working at my DE

Comment: thanks @santanu - i copied your example verbatim and only changed the recURL to a valid lead ID in my instance.  I'm finding that it will open in a new tab every time - it will never open in a subtab.  That is why it appears to work on the nav tab.  Try opening a case and clicking the link - does it open in a subtab for you?

Comment: it is working fine